# External HDD freezes computer and does not show up in Disk Management

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, external-hard-drive, freeze, disk-management

I have a Seagate 1TB external hard drive. I was doing a full reformat of the drive the other day and unfortunately, my pc crashed while it was at 94%.

After a reboot, my pc was completely stuck and would not even show the initial splash screen to access the bios until I disconnected the drive I was formatting.

Furthermore, after signing in and reconnecting the drive it does not show up in File Explorer, Disk Management, or Diskpart. However, it does show up in device manager but whenever I try to interact with like populating the volumes, installing new drivers, etc it makes my computer freeze up and hang until it is disconnected from the USB port.

The drive also makes a noticeable beeping sound coming from the enclosure upon startup which I did not notice before.

I have tried a lot of troubleshooting through the bios and various disk utilities but I can't seem to be able to even find the drive so I'm not sure what to do.

This is not a new drive, it is well past its warranty and I would like to continue using it.

Comment: I would start by looking in the Windows Event Viewer logs and see if there are any applicable errors.

Comment: I could'nt seem to find any errors applicable to my situation in the event logs. However, I could totally be missing something. I'll attach a screenshot of the Event Logs at the time of the crash down below. I also don't see any new errors pop up when the device is plugged in. [link](https://gyazo.com/d3a42882c4c5bd0c85e6a6487d302349) screenshot

Comment: you have a lot of events there. If it were my machine, I would start chipping my through the list and fixing what I could. There are certainly some events that may indeed be related to the issue you describe. Google will be your friend

Comment: It's unlikely the drive experienced hardware damage from the abrupt loss of power during a full format - verify via [smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download). Windows isn't the best OS for correcting what went wrong because of how it accesses drives, which may also result in hangs from running `smartctl` on Windows. If accessing S.M.A.R.T data shows no hardware issue, or if it hangs in Windows, boot a Linux LiveUSB, install `smartmontools` and use a Linux utility to format _(or use Hiren's and boot a DOS partition tool)_

Answer (score 0):

This interesting. I think it is a bad drive. I have a 1tb hard drive that i pulled out of an xbox one s. The xbox wouldn't boot it would freeze in the startup. Now that i have the drive plugged into my computer (windows 11) it freezes up disk manager and does not display on anything except for device manager. I've come to the conclusion that its just a bad drive.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1211638)